# ASP.NET/IIS: Windows Authentication, setting max attempts and redirecting

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, active-directory

We have an internal web app running on IIS6 and we use the integrated windows authentication for domain users to login to the app before they can use it.

What we would like to do is redirect the user to an error page if they fail to login to the domain 3 times.

Where should i be looking to configure this? My first thought was in IIS, but i don't see anything in the config there that relates to what i'm looking to do.

Comment: I think if you set the site as trusted or local intranet they will not be prompted for their credentials, could be pushed out via group policy

Comment: I'd agree with Jon. It's a great example of working smarter and feasibly passing the buck in a good way, which may offset some liability and future maintenance (if group policy changes) to the sys admin.

Answer (score 2):

How are the users authenticating? If they are using IE then domain authentication should be automatic (ie. the server does an NTLM challenge to the browser which is handled automatically by IE if the web server is in the intranet zone). In this case it would not be possible to fail to log in if the user is a member of the domain.

If you are using a login form which then then verifies the credentials against the domain controller, then you can implement a custom solution which counts the invalid logins and does a Response.Redirect to an error page.

Without knowing more about the setup it is difficult to answer more fully...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd make this database driven. assuming the user enters the username credentials correctly but fails to enter the correct password. When they do login correctly, set their FailLoginCount to 0, and eachtime they fail, increase it by one.

Once it reaches 3, redirect them to your desired page and possible "lock" their account.

HTH